# How to create a automatic Field value number to display in the lable for an custom content type: Itinerary e.g Day 1, Day 2

Tags: entities

I have a content type which I've called Itineraries which lists activities users will do on certain days of the package. I've created a 'day' field which the admin will populate with each day's activities, the value is set to unlimited as some packages have 7 days and others 21 days - how do I get the label of each field to automatically set to the number of values sumbitted by the admin ?

So if the admin enters 3 values it should display the label for each submission as - 
Day 1 :
fishing, running ...
Day 2: 
camping
Day 3:
drive home

I've looked at the Computed field but lack the php knowledge to implement.

Is there another way of implementing the above ? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using computed field you could do this.

1. Install computed_field module
2. add a field into the content type you want to count the field for, and then in the display code box add this (field_slect is the field you want to count)

   $display_output = sizeof(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_select'));